# Can I prevent a named application changing the CPU's frequency?

Tags: power-management

I have an Intel server. The CPUs are power managed between 800MHz and 3GHz, using the p_state driver. Obviously it's drawing less power and making less noise when it's down at 800Mhz.

Most of the things that are running on the server are on-demand and should execute as fast as possible (and they do) but I have one daemon that is thoroughly unimportant. It takes about 20% CPU at peak but this can last for a few hours while it processes files.

My problem is whenever this process does anything, the power state in the CPU ramps up. It uses more power and makes more noise. I want this one daemon to run at 800MHz all the time (unless anything else needs the CPU).

I could stick the whole server in powersave but I need other applications to be able to scale the CPU. Is there a sensible way I can tell whatever manages the CPU to disregard load from a particular application?

Answer (score 6):

I found [`cpulimit`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96387/run-program-at-lower-cpu-speed).

```
$ sudo apt-get install cpulimit  # for installing cpulimit
$ pgrep process_to_limit         # getting the pid
1234

$ cpulimit -p 1234 -l 30         # -p pid -l percentage_of_cpu_to_use
```

But it looks like `cpulimit` only uses the pid of a running process or executes a program. That means you need to find a way (bash script) to execute cpulimit when the daemon is running.

Here's a short shell script that reads the pid, executes cpulimit and sleeps for 60min.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This example uses firefox, replace the variable PROG

PROG=firefox
PID=`pgrep $PROG`

if [ $PID ]                # if $PID not equals 0 (zero)
then
   cpulimit -p $PID -l 30  # limit the cpu time to 30%
   sleep 60m               # wait 60 minutes
else
   sleep 60m
fi
```

Save it as e.g. `run_cpulimit.sh`, grant permission `chmod u+x run_cpulimit.sh` and start it.

Comment: "Since you have a reputation of 151k I will not include installation instructions." You should always include the install instruction, yes oli is the highest rep user on the site but your answers should be for anyone that reads this, not just the OP, what about new users who look for this information???.

Comment: Okay you are right, I just wanted to be lazy, maybe it was the wrong time :D

Comment: Good edit, but be careful, laziness will get you downvoted because of lack of detail.

Comment: I do not understand the "limit the cpu speed to 30%, makes 900MHz" statement in the context of the intel_pstate driver in powersave mode. Typically 30% load will result in a higher CPU frequency (depending on the processor). It is also somewhat a function of if the load is increasing or decreasing. I'm suggesting a lower number might be needed.

Comment: The OP wrote that he has an Intel CPU that clocks from 800MHz up to 3GHz. When the daemon is running, it takes all ressources it can, so he need to have a mechanism that limits the max CPU speed for that process and that mechanism is `cpulimit`. Instead of limiting to a specific frequency that program limits the max CPU speed in percentage. So 30% of 3GHz is 900MHz.

Comment: The cpulimit program limits the percentage of cputime allowed to to be used by the task, independent of the CPU clock frequency (or speed, if you will). 30% does not mean 900MHz, it means you will observe a maximum  of 30% (or thereabouts) with `top'.

Comment: @Doug For my understanding: Isn't it like this. You have a CPU with 3GHz, that's 3,000,000,000 calculations per seconds. Now you limit the time for a process, let's say from 100% to 30%, that would make 900,000 calculations per second, which would be 900MHz. I know that some CPU time goes to the OS (Kernel, Scheduler,...), but theoretically, isn't that what's about?

Comment: No. Consider a cpu time wasting type program (no I/O wait and minimal system calls) that prints elapsed time every so often. Unrestricted, mine prints every 5.55 seconds and is running at 3.8 GHz (it is noisy). At a cpulimit of 20% it prints every 43 seconds and is running at about 2.1 GHz.. 5.55 * 3.8 / 2.1 * 100 / 20 = 50 seconds. A straight scaling would have been 27.5 seconds.